# Volume of solid of rotation about x-axis

Tags: integration

Rotation of the region bounded by $x=2y^2-1,\; x=y^2$  and $x$-axis about $x$-axis.

I draw out the graph, and found intersection is at $(1,1)$ and $(-1,-1)$

So is it correct to continue doing by finding volume of region from $x=-1$ to $1$ under the graph $x=2y^2-1$ plus the volume of region from $1$ to infinity under the graph $x=y^2$?  Did I do this correctly?

Anyone can help?  Thanks!

Comment: I think you are only supposed to consider the region that is to the left of $x=y^2$ from $y=-1$ to $y=1$.

Comment: @DavidK erm , is it only consider x=2y^2-1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Picture of the Graph]

Here is a plot of the two curves. Since the region between the two curves to the right of their intersection is not bounded, we do not need to calculate that volume (which is also unbounded). The volume in question is the one found in the region $-1<x<1$ when the curves have been rotated.

Now we rearrange the formulae for the first curve to get $y^2=\frac{x+1}{2}$. Then, using our standard formula for finding a volume of revolution, and splitting our solid into two parts, we have

$$\text{Volume} = \pi\int_{-1}^0 \left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right) \mathrm{d}x + \pi\int_0^1 \left(\frac{x+1}{2} - x \right) \mathrm{d}x$$ which you can evaluate by standard methods.

Comment: @elDino May I ask why need to minus x in the integral, I thought the revolution is overlapping?

Comment: Because you're trying to find the volume obtained through revolving the difference between the two curves.

Comment: is the ans pi? thank you!

Comment: That's what I got! No problem :)

Comment: @elDin0 You get $\pi$ because $\int_{-1}^1 x\,dx = 0.$ That is, you are actually computing the volume between $y^2=\frac{x+1}{2}$ and the line $x=1$. To do this correctly via the disk/annulus method, you need to treat the intervals $-1<x<0$ and $0<x<1$ separately. Alternatively, use the shell method.

Comment: @DavidK oh yes, I apologise. I must have been half asleep doing that. I'll edit my answer now.

Comment: @elDin0 Looks good now.